# having a service like this is wrong in linux?

Tags: linux, go, service, daemon

Let's say I have a service that makes constant requests to a web server and then checks if a certain condition is met, and if it does, it executes a function and then makes requests again. What I say, in golang could be represented like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for {
        a, _ := http.Get("https://example.com");

        if a.StatusCode == 200 {
            break;
        }
    }

    fmt.Print("Siguiente codigo...");
}
```

It's a somewhat vague example, but it represents what I'm saying, but then, would making requests that often waste a lot of resources? How often should I make requests? Is there any other better way I can do it? I would like to say that for my specific case the check must be done very often, so the loop must be executed more or less frequently.

Comment: Never execute polling requests in a "tight loop". You will hit rate limits and/or exhaust your resources. Put a reasonable sleep (or use a ticker) in between requests.

Comment: You need to monitor the health of your web site? How often shoud it be done? Once in a minute is fine? Then do it every minute.

Comment: *"How often should I make requests? Is there any other better way I can do it? "* - all information available state that you need to make these requests and make them very often. No more information are given than this, so it cannot be said how often you should make it (depends on your unknown requirements) and if there are alternatives (depend on what you do the requests for and if there are alternative ways to get the information you need - both unknown). This means that there are no information provided which are needed to answer the question.